# Word Form - using VBA to enable textbox on checkbox click

Tags: forms, vba, ms-word

I have the following VBA code to enable a textbox everytime a checkbox is clicked.

```
Private Sub CheckName1_Click()
If CheckName1.Value = True Then
    TextName1.Enabled = False
    TextName1.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
Else
    TextName1.Enabled = True
    TextName1.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectSunken
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is my document will probably have 30 of these by the time I am done (CheckName1, CheckName2, CheckRent1, CheckRent2, etc). I am already having trouble with Word lagging, so I'd like to create a subroutine that will call this sub instead of copy/pasting it again and again.

I haven't spent a lot of time with functions and the like- and even less with VBA. I just know the basics and they always make my head spin.  So, this is what I have.

I just don't know how to pass the textbox parameter, or if I even have the checkbox parameter right.

And if this is close, do I still create a call for each checkbox?

```
Private Sub CheckName1_Click()
    Call NA
End Sub

Private Sub NA(checkbox, textbox)
If checkbox.value = True Then
    textbox.Enabled = False
    textbox.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
Else
    textbox.Enabled = True
    textbox.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectSunken
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Could you make it clear what you want the buttons to do when clicked?

Comment: @ajgarmar, when the check box is clicked, the text box next to it needs to be disabled and "hidden".  When the check box is unchecked the user will need the textbox next to it to enter information.

Comment: The current code does this, I just think there is a way to have this happen without 8 lines of code per checkbox!

Answer (score 2):

Loop on all controls
Based on this example: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/control-loop.htm

```
Dim cCont As Control

    For Each cCont In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(cCont) = "TextBox" Then
            'DO STUFF HERE
        End If
     Next cCont
```

Comment: I could try this, but can you help me with one thing first? I'm not sure a loop is what I want. I just want to change one box per click, as each checkbox controls a different textbox.